# mysql loop - pre-load data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am putting together a drag-and-drop page, with the draggable boxes containing content populated by an sql table.  Once a box is dragged away, it disappears and a new one appears with fresh data.

I would only like to have 15 boxes appear at any one time, but I am not sure how to do this with SQL, since the dragging/dropping of boxes occurs after loading, and so php won't help me - do I need to pre-load the list of box names into a js array before the page loads?  Does that mean my entire list is then exposed to the public?

I have written this already using an xml table, and I am migrating to sql.  This is the function I wrote which is called every time a JQuery drop event occurs:

```
function AddNextSkill() {

var div = document.getElementById('productbox');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<div class="product" id= "box' + RunningCount +' "><h4>' + MyToolList[RunningCount][1] + "</h4></div>";
RunningCount += 1;
$("#productbox .product").draggable({//JQUERY DETAILS//}
});
```

In this case I made a pre-loaded array in JS MyToolList[i][j], which contains a list of tools and their id's.

Is this an inefficient way of doing this?  Would it be better to use sql and not preload any tables?

Comment: Well, I think you could either: load like 50 items, hide 35, and everytime a drop event occurs show another item OR load 15 items, and everytime a drop event occurs do an ajax call to load 1 more item.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing the following:

I created an AJAX call that returns only the next line in the table (with a

```
LIMIT $_GET[rownum], 1
```

call at the end of the SQL query.  I then called this AJAX call every time a drop event occurred.  The only trick is that you have to re-establish the new box as droppable.

```
function AddNewRow() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var div = document.getElementById('productbox');
            div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "AddNewTool.php?rownum=" + RunningCount, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

   $("#productbox .product").draggable({//JQUERY DETAILS//}
   });
```